# Is there a way to change where a hotbar is in terms of layering?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I am currently trying to set up my hotbars. A jank setup I have has one of my set of hotbars colliding with and covering some other parts of my hud with some of it. I want to know if there is a way to change the layering of it so it would be below the other elements instead of above them.

Below is a screenshot of what I am doing, showing that the extra hotbar is going over the other two instead of under them. That hotbar is number 5.

[image: This is the picture of the hud layout.]

Comment: Just curious, but if you replaced hotbar 2 with something like hotbar 8, would 5 still be on top or on bottom?  E.g. is the default Z order placement putting higher hotbars over lower ones?  If so, that would be one workaround - use higher hotbar numbers for your main bars.

Comment: @troyen I will try that out soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there doesn't seem to be a setting to control the Z-order of hotbars, there *is* a setting to hide unassigned slots that would hide the parts of the bar that currently overlaps.

It's in System, Character Configuration, Hotbar Settings side tab, Display tab.
[image: FFXIV Hide Unassigned slots]

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, though I  still wonder if there is a way to change the z order of hotbars. I am gonna accept this as it solved my problem, but if a way to change the z order arises (as unlikely as it is as of now) I will probably switch to that.

Comment: @ShadowZ.One other thing to try is to see if the Z-order changes when you click on the hotbars in the System, HUD Layout screen.